# Recipe linkandpostlink failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: qt

When I try to run a qt application on a Symbian device (N8 for example), I receive the following:

```
warning: Missing dependency detected: C:/QtSDK/Symbian/SDKs/Symbian3Qt473/epoc32/release/armv5/lib/kqoauthd0.dso
error: Recipe linkandpostlink failed with exit code 1.
```

Any one hear about that type of error?

Comment: The last line just means the build failed. Possibly because of the warning line, or stuff before it. It's a generic error.

Comment: That is right this file cannot be generated for unknown reason and I am sure this is the problem but how can I solve it?

I think there is something to add in the .pro file to include a .dll library which I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved !!! The problem was that I am including a .dll library, this works great for the simulator but not for the device, so the idea was to include all .h and .cpp files if the target is a symbian device, and the .dll library if the target is the simulator.